# React Native fetch data from Express.js server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-native, backend

EDIT: This was fixed by switching to a different Android phone emulator

I'm trying to create a simple React Native app that first off would fetch a json file from Express backend.

Backend:

```
...data to be fetched up here in a dictionary

//Enable CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/sightings', (req, res) => {
  res.json(sightings);
});

app.post('/sightings', (req, res) => {
  req.body.id = (sightings.length + 1).toString();
  sightings.push(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});

app.get('/species', (req, res) => {
  res.json(species);
});

const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 8081;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server listening  port %s", port);
});
```

Frontend:

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            key: '',
            sightings: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://10.0.0.2:3000/sightings')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({sightings: res })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        console.log(this.state.sightings);
    }
```

Obviously the point here is to update sightings in state with the data, but it's not working, I'm only returned the empty object assigned to this.state.sightings originally.

Is there some step I'm missing? I'm very much a beginner with using a node server and the various tutorials I followed did it just like this.

[data on local host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFgWJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is an async function, it takes time to complete. If you want to log the updated state, the precise way is to log it in the callback of this.setState. This should work,

```
      fetch('http://10.0.0.2:3000/sightings')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({sightings: res }, () => {
                   console.log(this.state.sightings);
                })
            })
            .catch ((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Go through the documentation to understand how setState works, https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: This did not fix the problem, it's behaving still in the exact same way

Comment: Can you log the `res` before setState? What does it show?

Comment: Then it seems the error with data fetching. Use debug mode to set the breakpoints in your code and check where it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, turns out everything worked correctly but the Android emulator I was using (Pixel_API_26) did not. When I switched to Nexus_4_API_23 everything worked as they should.